# How do I avoid typing "git" at the begining of every Git command?

Tags: git, version-control, command-line-interface, git-bash

I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid having to type the word `git` at the beginning of every Git command.

It would be nice if there was a way to use the `git` command only once in the beginning after opening a command prompt to get into *"Git mode"*.

For example:

```
git>
```

After which every command we type is by default interpreted as a Git command.

In a way similar to how we use the MySQL shell to write database commands:

```
mysql>
```

This will save me from having to type `git` hundreds of times a day.

**NOTE:** I'm using [`git-bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bash), on Windows.

Comment: To those who have voted to close on the basis of it being off-topic, please read the text you are clicking on: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.**". Git is a tool used by programmers. As evidenced by the fact that it has its own tag on this site.

Comment: Similar: [Omit “git” from series of git commands](https://superuser.com/q/1280747/354511).

Comment: Why are you typing "git" so much? Your IDE should have powerful vcs integrations available at a keypress. Do you rather type "git pull" 50 times a day, or ctrl-t... stop *being a command line warrior* when you dont need to be ;)

Comment: @vikingsteve Practically *all* git help and wisdom is given in terms of command-line.

Comment: @vikingsteve I'm typing it so much because it's faster. I type ~100wpm, more if I'm intimately familiar with the keypresses like I am with Git; compared to clicking on GUIs, it's just easier. Your favorite IDE may have keyboard shortcuts. That's nice for you. Why would *I* waste time learning them when <M-Tab>git blah<CR> is already in my muscle memory?

Comment: Use Fish, its memory command in bash. Very speed writing.

Comment: There should be a "this question should be closed because the user is asking a question that doesn't make sense" - like I get what you're asking but how is the shell going to know you want to enter a "non starting with git command" if there was indeed a way to do this.

Comment: I just use a quick `alias g=git`

Comment: I've created a Python script called [NoGit](https://github.com/LogicalBranch/NoGit) for this.

Answer (score 192):

You might want to try [gitsh](https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh). From their readme:

> The `gitsh` program is an interactive shell for git. From within `gitsh` you can issue any git command, even using your local aliases and configuration.
>
> - Git commands tend to come in groups. Avoid typing `git` over and over and over by running them in a dedicated git shell:
>
> ```
> sh$ gitsh
> gitsh% status
> gitsh% add .
> gitsh% commit -m "Ship it!"
> gitsh% push
> gitsh% ctrl-d
> sh$
> ```

Or have a look at the other projects linked there:

> - [git-sh](https://github.com/rtomayko/git-sh) - A customised bash shell with a Git prompt, aliases, and completion.
> - [gitsh](https://github.com/caglar/gitsh) - A simple Git shell written in Perl.
> - [repl](https://github.com/defunkt/repl) - Wraps any program with subcommands in a REPL.

Note: Haven't used this myself.

Comment: *grumble*... `repl(1)` is not a REPL. It doesn't eval or print anything. It runs programs.

Comment: @Kevin It reads in user requests, evaluate the user request (by running a program), and prints the output of the program.  This is also what shells do.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: No, it most certainly does not "print the output of the program." It hooks the program's stdout up to the terminal, and then the program prints its own output - except the program's stdout is already hooked up to the terminal (inherited automatically over the `fork()`/`exec()`), so `repl(1)` isn't even doing *that*.

Comment: @Kevin I understand your sentiment, however the strict definition of a REPL would exclude _most_ interpreter “REPL”s in various languages. Only in pure functional languages could you ensure that the evaluation has no side-effects, but even in Haskell the “REPL” GHCi will by default also accept `IO` actions, and execute them including side-effects such as printing to the terminal-connected screen.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I never said anything about side effects. I just said that a read, eval, print loop should actually read, eval, and print.

Comment: @Kevin `repl` isn't a standalone REPL; it's a means of creating a REPL system in which `repl` is only the interactive component. Is that fair?

Comment: @Kyle: I didn't say it had to be standalone either. Why is everyone so intent on putting words in my mouth?

Comment: @Kevin I wasn't trying to rephrase what you said, merely to provide an explanation of what `repl` is and why it's named that way that you might agree with. I take it you don't agree with the "REPL system in which `repl` is only the interactive component" explanation, then? Why not?

Comment: I wonder why no one did came with *gisht* as project name. It means finger in Albanian.

Answer (score 117):

A Perl one-liner which will do this:

```
perl -nE 'BEGIN {print "git > "} system "git $_"; print "git > "'
```

This will execute whatever you type, prefixed with `git`. And it will keep doing that until you hit `^D`.

Comment: This really is most similar to what OP is asking for, and in a very lightweight package!

Comment: This would be perfect if it worked with readline but unfortunately it doesn’t (not surprisingly since this is strictly a hack around Perl’s `-ne` flags).

Comment: @KonradRudolph `perl -MTerm::ReadLine -E '$n = Term::ReadLine -> new ("git"); while ($_ = $n -> readline ("git > ")) {system "git $_"}'`

Answer (score 56):

This is not exactly what you're asking for, but you could set up some shell aliases in your `~/.bashrc` for the Git commands you use most frequently:

```
alias commit='git commit'
alias checkout='git checkout'
...
```

Also note that you can create aliases within Git itself:

```
git config --global alias.ci commit
git config --global alias.co checkout
...
```

This lets you type `git ci` instead of `git commit`, and so on.

Comment: The drawback of this approach is that a separate alias would need to be created for every Git command.

Comment: Only for the most frequently used. I mean, how often do you use `git hash-object` or `git interpret-trailers`? I'm just offering this as an alternative because as far as I know, what the question is asking for doesn't really exist.

Comment: In addition to `ci` for `commit` I also use a shell alias `g` for `git`, this reduces most of the typing and lets me stay in my preferred shell.

Answer (score 32):

I'm a big fan of using aliases in ~/.bash_profile for my GitBash. If you go with this approach, here are some of my favorites:

```
# git
alias gw='git whatchanged'
alias gg='git grep -n -C8'
alias ggi='git grep -i -n -C8'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gbd='git branch -D'
alias gba='git branch -a'
alias gc='git checkout'
alias gcp='git cherry-pick'
alias gfo='git fetch origin'
alias s='git status'
alias gmom='git merge origin/master'
alias grom='git rebase origin/master'
alias gpom='git pull origin master'
alias pplog='git log --oneline --graph --decorate'
```

Comment: where's commit :P

Comment: I don't include `commit` or `push` since I want a few extra seconds (while typing) to be sure that I'm not destroying something

Comment: Commit and push shouldn't be able to destroy anything unless you use force push. But I try to use git status beforehand.

Comment: this is what I've done as well, +1. Although I'm tempted to try gitsh as other answers have mentioned

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I respect the fact that you acknowledge that a few keystrokes is the difference between saving updates and destroying a project.

Comment: If you use oh-my-zsh there is a git plugin with a bunch of these predefined (can maybe be used for inspiration): https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh

Comment: I would actually recommend building commits with `git gui` because then you can easily commit modified lines instead of modified files.

Answer (score 32):

Use your editor.

Type the command like `commit` from your favorite editor like [vs code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and be more efficient with git:

[image]

Or type `git` to get all the commands:

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised by all these down votes. This isn't a terrible answer for people who use IDEs that support these features.

Comment: I think people have down-voted because not everyone uses/likes VS-Code. Either way, I think it's a decent solution so +1 from me.

Comment: @LogicalBranch, people are generally using the git from command line, and I am aware of that, but the git support inside some editors exists and it is worth trying.

Comment: I don't like this answer because not everyone uses VS code (I personally don't like it), but won't downvote because this is a nice solution for ppl that do use it.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso, if you are using sublime there is a plugin called [gitsavvy](https://github.com/divmain/GitSavvy), and so on... Almost every editor nowadays has some kind of support for git. This was the point of the answer, as you can read "Use your editor".

Comment: This mostly comes down to if someone uses many editors on the same os, or the same editor on many different os.

Comment: @prosti I either lots of different editors for different things (I use 2 or 3 different editors each day), or I use vim, so I just end up using the terminal since it's easier to avoid messing something up that way.

Comment: @IanRingrose I end up using different editors on different OSes.

Answer (score 26):

A friend of mine made a small bash script that accomplishes this. It's called [Replify](https://gist.github.com/danielrw7/bb88e3dad565c0d8ee54031f6b758a09).

```
$ replify git
Initialized REPL for [git]
git> init
Initialized empty Git repository in /your/directory/here/.git/

git> remote add origin https://your-url/repo.git

git> checkout -b new-branch
Switched to a new branch 'new-branch'

git> push
```

Comment: OK, I've already mentioned that on Umur's answer, but the use of `eval` in the original script source isn't the best idea. Tell your friend to use `while IFS= read -r -p "git> " gitcmd; do [ "x$gitcmd" != "x" ] && git "$gitcmd";done` instead

Comment: Add flag `-e` to the `read` to use readline editing. Sadly it doesn't seem to remember previous commands but uses actual shell history. I also recommend `-p "$ git "` to make it easier to understand what you're actually commanding.

Answer (score 23):

Here is another way. It's also not quite what was asked, but I've been using it for some time and it is pretty nice. Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
complete -E -W git
```

Now pressing Tab at an empty Bash prompt will type out "git ".

Comment: Note that if you're using another shell, you'll have to put it in the appropriate file. For example, for zsh, you'll put it in `~/zshrc`, for tcsh, you'll put it in `~/tcshrc`, etc.

Comment: This is actually *really* nice to do this. This allows you use all the shell commands at will but you can just type e.g. `tab` `status` or `tab` `fetch` to run git commands. If you have some alias you can run that command and maybe change the prompt to have your "git environment".

Answer (score 20):

### Introduction:

If you want you can just create your own CLI for `git`, I wrote a script to solve this exact problem. [NoGit](https://github.com/LogicalBranch/NoGit) is a simple python script to prevent the unnecessary repetition of the "git" keyword.

### Update (23/06/2022):

At the time of this update, this answer was 3 years, 1 week, and 6 days old. I've since come back and fixed a conflict error caused by [NoGit](https://github.com/LogicalBranch/NoGit)'s `./git` executable and the actual `git` executable and made some minor changes to the behaviour of the `.history` file. The GitHub page for the project and it's associated article (linked on the project's GitHub page) have also been updated.

### Installation:

To run NoGit, you need [Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installed on your system. You can download the script from the official [repository](https://github.com/LogicalBranch/NoGit) or copy the source code below.

**Note**: The script depends on the [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html), [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html), [readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) and [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) modules.

### Installation notes (Linux):

If you want you can remove the `.py` extension and convert it into an executable:

```bash
mv nogit.py nogit
chmod +x ./nogit
./nogit # open the NoGit CLI
```

You can also move this script to your `./bin/` directory and create an alias for it to run it without a `./`:

```bash
sudo cp ./nogit /bin/nogit
sudo chmod +x /bin/nogit
alias nogit="/bin/nogit"
```

Alternatively you can copy the following command into your CLI:

```bash
git /bin/nogit && sudo chmod +x /bin/nogit && alias nogit='/bin/nogit'
```

### Documentation:

- `%undo` deletes the last command from the stack
- `%run`executes all commands in the stack and deletes it when done
- `%exit` closes the CLI without doing anything
- `ctrl+c` has the same effect as executing `%run; %exit` or `%run` and `%exit`
- Command history gets saved to a file called `nogit.history` in the same folder as the script
- You can add multiple commands in one line using a semi-colon
- You can use the `git` keyword because the script doesn't add the `git` keyword if it already exists

### Demonstration:

1. `init`
2. `add -A`
3. `stage -A`
4. `status`
5. `commit -m "initial commit"`
6. `%run; %exit`

### Source code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, signal, atexit, readline, subprocess

commands, stop, history_file = [], False, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "nogit.history")

def run_commands():
  stop = True
  for cmd in commands:
    command = ["git" if not cmd.startswith("git ") else ""]
    command = [cmd] if command[0] == "" else [command[0], cmd]
    subprocess.Popen(command).communicate()
    commands = []

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
  run_commands()
  sys.exit(0)

try:
  readline.read_history_file(history_file)
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
  while True:
    if stop == True:
      break
    command = input("git> ")
    if command == "%undo":
      commands.pop()
    elif command == "%run":
      run_commands()
    elif command == "%exit":
      sys.exit(0)
    else:
      commands += [cmd.strip() for cmd in command.split(";")]
  signal.pause()
  readline.set_history_length(-1)
except IOError:
  pass

atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, history_file)
```

Answer (score 17):

Another approach that will work with any commands: use Ctrl+R (reverse-i-search).

The reverse-i-search allows you to search your command history. Repeat Ctrl+R after pressing your search string to repeat search further back with the same string.

You only need to type a command once, then you can recall that command from any substrings of the command. In most cases, you can recall entire very long commands and their various variants with just two to three well-placed search letters. No preconfigurations needed other than using your shell normally and it is self-adaptive to how you used the shell, simply type the full command once and the commands would be automatically added to your command history.

- `git commit --amend`: `<Ctrl+R>am`
- `git pull`: `<Ctrl+R>pu`
- `git rebase --rebase-merges -i --onto origin/develop origin/develop feature/blue-header`: `<Ctrl+R>blu`
- `git rebase --abort`: `<Ctrl-R>ab`
- `git rebase --continue`: `<Ctrl-R>con`
- `docker-compose stop && git pull && make && docker-compose up -d`: `<Ctrl-R>up`
- etc

Moreover, Ctrl-R works not on just bash, but a lot of programs that uses readline library (and there are a lot of them), like Python shell, IPython, mysql shell, psql shell, irb (ruby), etc.

Answer (score 15):

In your example, you compare it to a MySql prompt. The way that works is that a MySql process starts, and you give your commands to that process. As such, why not write something similar in your language of choice? Here's a simple example in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    while(true){
        std::cout << "git> ";
        std::cout.flush();
        std::string command;
        std::getline(std::cin, command);
        if(command == "exit") break;
        std::system("git " + command);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that I just wrote that from memory and that I didn't check it with a compiler. There may be trivial syntax errors.

Comment: Just my thought. Anyone on Stack Overflow should be able to code such a program himself. The programming language does not really matter.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I definitely agree. I posted the program to precisely show what I was talking about, not because it is a difficult program to write.

Comment: You're going to invest a lot of time with this approach if you want the program to be bug-free and have a decent amount of features. For example, after fixing the initial build failure (std::system() wants const char*) you'll notice that there is an infinite loop on EOF. You might want history/readline support, tab completion, some builtins to change directory / set env vars / shell out / ..., etc. If there is existing software (like gitsh in this case), why not use it?

Comment: @nomadictype That's a valid criticism, but learning other software is also a time commitment. The advantages with this approach are that only a few minutes are needed to get it working, and thst it will do *exactly* what you expect or want (with changes).

Comment: The loss of readline, line editing, history support, being able to run simple commands like ls, etc is going to cost you a lot more than the four keystrokes or so you saved with this.

Answer (score 13):

For basic stuff, you can do:

```sh
function ggit(){ while true; do printf 'git> '; read; eval git $REPLY; done }
```

```
git> status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    yarn.lock

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
git> add .
git> status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    yarn.lock

git>
```

Exit with ctrl+c

Comment: Decent idea, however there's two problems. One, the `;` after do leads to `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'` Second, the `eval` part is prone to vulnerabilities. For example, consider what happens if I type `status;cat /etc/passwd` into this small shell. Harmless example, but you get the idea what can happen .You can simplify that into `while IFS= read -r -p "git> " gitcmd; do [ "x$gitcmd" != "x" ] && git "$gitcmd";done` This of course is not bullet proof, but 1 - it is simpler and 2 - avoids non-git command execution (by virtue of double quotes ). Not ideal, just a little better

Comment: @Abigail  Funny :) Why yes, shell itself isn't the most secure application. Even [catting a file](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/56391/121824) can be a problem. However, the point I was originally making is that we don't see mysql interpreter executing shell commands, not without `system` or `\!` at the beginning at least. Where the assumption might be that this "repl" executes `git` commands only, it in fact allows more than that.

Comment: @Abigail  I am not afraid, because I know what this does. Others who don't - may end up breaking something they shouldn't.   And again - `eval`  isn't the best idea for running commands, especially when user-controlled input is involved.

Comment: Fixed the typo after `do`. Thanks!

re: security: This is obviously not meant to be distributed as a separate application. Just put in your `.bash_profile` if you don't like typing git. I'm not too worried about it being "insecure". If you paste stuff in your bash that you don't understand (including this oneliner script), you're gonna have a bad time.

I like this because it's simple, easy to write and easy to read, and easy to improve upon.

Answer (score 2):

When I used Windows 7 with Conemu, I added the following to my dev environment startup script:

```
doskey g=git $*
```

With this, I could just use the `g` command instead of typing `git`.
Last I tried with Windows 10 and Conemu, it did not work, there is a bug, I think, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Use a brackets editor, it's easy to use your code and git commands, it also has many features.

[image]

To the top right corner the second binocular icon is used to install extensions.

[image]

Search extension `brackets git` like the above image and install it.

[image]

Again to the top right corner there will show the fourth icon, so just click and see the changes like the above image.

If you want to install brackets, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

For more information, you can read: [How to Install Brackets Code Editor in Ubuntu and Linux Mint](https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-brackets-code-editor-in-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/) on [Ubuntupit](https://www.ubuntupit.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> After

```
while read -erp "*git*${PS1@P}" cmd rest; do 
        if _=`git help $cmd 2>&-`
                then eval git $cmd "$rest"
                else eval $cmd "$rest"
        fi
done
```

> every command we type is by default interpreted as a Git command

if it looks like one, otherwise it'll be interpreted as-is, so you can intermix git with other commands, and if you want to use a punned command just prefix it with a backslash, `rm foo` would be eval'd as `git rm foo`, but `\rm foo` would run the plain `rm` command. ^d out as usual to end it.

Answer (score 0):

Since today: [GitHub CLI](https://github.blog/2020-09-17-github-cli-1-0-is-now-available/) is available.

> GitHub CLI brings GitHub to your terminal.  It reduces context
> switching, helps you focus, and enables you to more easily script and
> create your own workflows. Earlier this year, we announced the beta of
> GitHub CLI. Since we released the beta, users have created over
> 250,000 pull requests, performed over 350,000 merges, and created over
> 20,000 issues with GitHub CLI. We’ve received so much thoughtful
> feedback, and today GitHub CLI is out of beta and available to
> download on Windows, macOS, and Linux.